# Maven distributionManagement

Tags: maven

I develop a web application, and I am about to deploy in the server artifactory anonymously. I have distinguished the snapshot and release repositories with the corresponding artifactory url in the distributionManagement of my parent POM. The problem is that the deployment is always done in release and not in snapshot. Help me make the deposit in release and snapshot.
Here is my distributionManagement:

```
<distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>My release</id>
            <name>Release</name>
            <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>repo/artifacotry/release</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>My snapshot</id>
            <name>Snapshot</name>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>repo/artifacotry/snapshot</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Comment: Ensure that you do not have a rogue `distributionManagement` section in another pom somewhere. Also ensure that the content of your `<url>...</url>` elements is spelt correctly!

Comment: There is only one distributionmanagement tag in my parent pom. When I change the link of the snapshot and I put in the repository of the release the deployment is done directly in the snapshot repository. I think this is not a link problem. Somewhere the operation of the two depots is not active. How to activate both to deploy in artifactory?

Comment: What do you have in the pom.xml's `<version>...</version>` tags? Only artefacts with a version terminated with `-SNAPSHOT` will be deployed to the `snapshotRepository`.

Comment: If it is deployed to the release repository I assume you are using a release version like `1.2.3` without `-SNAPSHOT` ...

Comment: Yes, that's it, I had a version without snapshot. Is it possible to have a version that is able to deploy in snapshot and in release or must always specify the version?

Comment: You have to give a version either a release version or a SNAPSHOT version...I don't see your problem?

Comment: The problem is resolved, it was necessary to specify either a version snapshot or release.
Thank you for your help